# Save/load Vis.js network layout and data

Tags: javascript, html, vis.js

I'm currently working on a small game that involves a series of nodes I've built using Vis.js. The majority of the nodes are hidden at the start, and get revealed as the game progresses. I originally wanted to simply JSON.stringify my nodes object, and then .parse it back in before the network loads.

```
$("#testbutton").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('nodes', JSON.stringify(nodes));
});
```

followed by

```
if(!(localStorage.getItem('nodes') === null)) {
    nodes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nodes'));
}
```

However, I get an error of 'array or dataset expected' when it tries to load the new nodes object into the network. I'm honestly not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: I guess you can print out the resulting string from `JSON.stringify()` and see that it does not contain the actual data of your graph.  It's an internal data structure used by Vis.js which is not the same as a Javascript data structure, such as a dictionary or array.